# Every method which is not called from outside class should be private in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class controller

```
class QueueMessagesController < SecureController

  def create
   create_queue_message(params) if params[:type] == 'cards'
   delete_queue_message(params)  if params[:type] == 'queue'
  end


   def create_queue_message(params)

   end

   def delete_queue_message(params)

   end


  private

   def queue_params
    params.require(:headers)
   end
end
```

So my query is whether the `create_queue_message` and `delete_queue_message`  should be private methods or not. what is good approach.

Comment: From the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions): _"Only public methods are callable as actions. It is a best practice to lower the visibility of methods (with  private or protected) which are not intended to be actions, like auxiliary methods or filters."_

Answer (score 2):

I would answer: Every method that is only used internally should be `private` in object-oriented-programming.

If you do not make such methods as private then another developer might think that they belong to the public API of the class and might use them directly.

Therefore I think it is a good practice to make all methods `private` as a default and only make a method public if there is a reason to add that method to the public API.

Comment: Got it Thank you

Comment: And special care has to be taken for Rails controllers – you don't want your internal method to be callable by users because you messed up the routes.

Comment: @Stefan  that is the exact reason I never have _any_ methods in controllers save for those responding to routes. Everything else could be done in a separate static fully functional module.